# set the text of a UILabel to a random object in an array

Tags: nsmutablearray, ios6, uilabel, xcode4.5

I am trying to make an xcode project that when the user hits a UIButton (IBAction) it sets the text of a UILabel to a **random** object in an NSMutable Array.  I do not want to use case and switches as it takes to long for my situation.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you assign the string to save the array and then on click you generate random number (max value is array size) and then assign to label i think it work

Comment: Yes I have done this, is there anyway of stoping the array from repeating an object as it is random, the label is sometimes setting to the same thing.

Comment: in this case i think this is done by you delete that value that is used